# YouTube Analytics - Video metrics

Tags: youtube-api

Had a question about querying channel reports filtered by video.  Can I assume that the sum of the metrics for all uploaded videos of a channel will be equal to the metrics if I queried without video filter?

In other words, if I make a report query for "views" for a channel between 1/1/2012 and 2/1/2012, I get a total views for that channel, say X.  Now if I query between the same date range, and filter by one video, I get views for just that video.  If I do this for every single video in the "upload" playlist for that channel and add up the views, will this equal X?

I assume it should but would like a confirmation.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't guarantee that, as I don't know how unlisted/private videos might affect that off the top of my head. I'd recommend that you run the queries and check for yourself (and post again letting us know).